# Pass SQL Query as parameter with single Quotes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have usecase to pass SQL query as parameter to a python script. SQL Query could be variables with diff table name/column names.

Query will be something in below format -

```
Select distinct col1, col2,...,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') load_date from <tabl_name> limit 10
```

I want to parameterize this query. However, when I pass the Query as parameter, single quotes(') inside the query makes python to look for a different column and I get the below error message :

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pg8000.core.ProgrammingError) ('ERROR', '42703', 'column "yyyy" does not exist in '

I tried \ or two single quotes('') as escape char but no luck. Can I pass the to_char

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the parameter worked when I pass the SQL with 3 double Quotes -

> python  """Select distinct col1,
>   col2,...,to_char(load_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') load_date from 
>   limit 10"""